# python. Из строки вывести все цифры одной строкой

Tags: python, строки, сортировка, filter, python-3.7

Дается строка из всевозможных символов (пример ввода:234олег7493не3знает//:-.
Строка обязательно заканчивается точкой.
Нужно вывести отсортированную в порядке убывания строку (повторяющиеся элементы удалить)  из ЦИФР 
(пример вывода для строки выше: 97432)
Желательно читабельный код,с эффективностью по времени и памяти. Строка на входе может быть любой.
Пытался через регулярные выражения с фильтром по //D,но получалачь чушь. Питон версии 3.7.2 (последняя,другие протестить не смогу)

Answer (score 1):

```
#234олег7493не3знает//:-.
print(''.join(sorted(list(set(filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), input()))), reverse=True)))
#97432
```

Answer (score 1):

Без лямбд:

```
s = "234олег7493не3знает//:-."
print (''.join(sorted([n for n in set(s) if n.isdigit()], reverse=True)))

# 97432
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
s = '234олег7493не3знает//:-.'
print(''.join(d for d in '9876543210' if d in s))
```

Время **O(n)**, память **O(1)**. Как в теории, так и на практике, решение очень эффективное.

С другой стороны, с точки зрения юникода, это тоже цифры:

➊➋➌➍➎➏➐➑➒  ₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉ ꘠꘡꘢꘣꘤꘥꘦꘧꘨꘩ и т.д.

и такоe решение их не отловит. Если это необходимо – лучше использовать `isdigit`